# Resampling Partial Month to Full End of Month - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, resampling

Putting this out there to see if there is a feasible solution for this.

Suppose I have a volumes for every month that say looked liked :

[image]

But if the start date for these volumes to be assigned is somewhere in a partial month, lets say in this example its 7/15/2023.

[image]

Is there a way to resample the data that sums of the correct volumes till the end of the month ? The answer should look like this.

[image]

I tried the simplae resampling , it just shifts the dates to the end of the month, but not in the way I wanted it to be. Any ideas?

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"DATE":["07/15/2023","08/15/2023","09/15/2023"], "VOL":[100, 150, 100]})
df['DATE']=df['DATE'].apply(pd.to_datetime)
df =df.resample('M', on='DATE').sum().reset_index()
print(df)
```

Comment: Why is the value for september `122.5806452`? Shouldn't it be `74.19354838709677` ?

Comment: the second month vol is 150 . but then the first month partial volume if pushed into second month + plus partial volume of the second month . that would make it 122.58 . If you see the totals for 3 months will be the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can do:

```py
import calendar

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {"DATE": ["07/15/2023", "08/15/2023", "09/15/2023"], "VOL": [100, 150, 100]}
)


def get_days_in_month(year, month):
    return calendar.monthrange(year, month)[1]

df["DATE"] = df["DATE"].apply(pd.to_datetime)

days_to_month_end = ((df["DATE"] + pd.offsets.MonthEnd()) - df["DATE"]).dt.days
days_in_month = df["DATE"].apply(lambda x: get_days_in_month(x.year, x.month))

tmp = df["VOL"] * days_to_month_end / days_in_month
df["RESULT"] = (df["VOL"].shift().fillna(0) - tmp.shift().fillna(0)) + tmp
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
        DATE  VOL      RESULT
0 2023-07-15  100   51.612903
1 2023-08-15  150  125.806452
2 2023-09-15  100  122.580645
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get the month end date and get the day difference from that first:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"DATE":["07/15/2023","08/15/2023","09/15/2023"], "VOL":[100, 150, 100]})

df['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE']) 
# Get Month End date
df['DATE_ME'] = df['DATE'] + pd.tseries.offsets.MonthEnd(0)
df['VOL'] * ((df['DATE_ME'].dt.day - df['DATE'].dt.day ) / df['DATE_ME'].dt.day )
```

OUTPUT:

```
0    51.612903
1    77.419355
2    50.000000
dtype: float64
```

Comment: I guess I can work with it . I need to do another diff on the remaining volumes and add that to this to get the answer I need. Thanks

Comment: I missed that part, I guess you can use `df.shift()` for that